# D3.js Force Layout path label is not moving correctly along the edge

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a force layout graph that draws correctly the edges and the nodes. The problem is with the label of the edges. They are drawn in a wrong position and they do not move along the edges when the graph is being moved. You can see the demo [here] (https://jsfiddle.net/calebgrangel/bgprcdpx/11/).
The interesting thing is that the edge that is created dynamically shows the edge label correctly. 
I inspected the SVG element through the browser and I found the comparison between the right one and the wrong one. There is a problem with the `transform` method for the `edgelabel` but don't know how to fix it.

```
<text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel3" dx="80" dy="0" font-size="15" fill="#aaa" style="pointer-events: none;" transform="rotate(180 615.890625 381.9453125)"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#edgepath3" style="pointer-events: none;">50</textPath>
</text>
```

and the wrong one is

```
<text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel2" dx="80" dy="0" font-size="15" fill="#aaa" style="pointer-events: none;"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#edgepath2" style="pointer-events: none;">30</textPath></text>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **not** the transform method of the `edgelabels` in the `tick()` function. Actually, you don't even need it, since they are text paths!

The problem here is different. When you do this:

```
graph.addNode('Node 1');
graph.addNode('Node 2');
graph.addNode('Node 3');
graph.addNode('Node 4');

graph.addLink('Node 1', 'Node 2', '10');
graph.addLink('Node 1', 'Node 3', '20');
graph.addLink('Node 2', 'Node 4', '30');
```

You are, for every one of those calls, calling `update()`, and this will mess with your chart.

**Solution**: remove `update()` from both `addNode()` and `addLink()` functions. Then, call it *after* adding the links and nodes:

```
graph = new myGraph("#svgdiv");

graph.addNode('Node 1');
graph.addNode('Node 2');
graph.addNode('Node 3');
graph.addNode('Node 4');

graph.addLink('Node 1', 'Node 2', '10');
graph.addLink('Node 1', 'Node 3', '20');
graph.addLink('Node 2', 'Node 4', '30');

graph.update();//calling update here
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dLo3v75c/

Comment: In the updated fiddle, when I click on the Add new Node and Edge Button the Node 5 is not added. Also, when I click in the Restart Graph button I have this `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M undefined unde…". attrFunction @ d3.v3.js:670`

Comment: Well, that's **another** problem. I just showed you the precise cause of the problem stated in your question's title and I even showed a solution which correctly fixes **that** specific problem. I didn't refactor your code to accommodate the fix, that's way beyond the scope of the question here.